# Strange behavior when python class variables and instance variables overlap

Tags: python, variables

```py
class TestClass():
    class_v = 0
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.class_v += 1
        TestClass.class_v += 1
        
        
        
print(TestClass.class_v) # 0

class_a = TestClass()
class_b = TestClass()

print(f'class_a.class_v = {class_a.class_v}') # 1
print(f'class_b.class_v = {class_b.class_v}') # 2
print(TestClass.class_v) # 2
```

In the python code above, when the names of the class variable and instance variable are the same, two instances were created with the same class, but the values are different when the variable is imported. If it is an instance variable, both must be 1, and if it is a class variable, both must be 2. How does python work?

```py
# ex
TestClass.class_v += 1
self.class_v += 1
```

If you change the order of the code blocks above, 2 and 3 are output instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to think of them as "attributes", not "variables". I'm guessing your confusion comes from thinking that the class's `class_v` and the instance's `class_v` are the same variable. They are not.

The class and the instance are two different objects, each with their own attributes, but instances can inherit attributes they haven't been assigned from their class. In `self.class_v += 1`, `self` doesn't have a `class_v` yet, so it retrieves a value from `TestClass.class_v`, then assigns the new value to `self.class_v`. In `TestClass.class_v += 1`, `TestClass` already has its own `class_v`, so the retrieval and assignment both deal with the same attribute.

Comment: To simplify things, we can say that `self.class_v += 1` is equivalent to `self.class_v = self.class_v + 1`, the right part of which fallbacks to `TestClass.class_v` whereas the left part sets an attribute in the instance's `.__dict__`.

Comment: @luther
Does doing self.class_v += 1 mean that self can refer to class variables, not instance variables?
If then,
Is this the right order to find the variables self.class_v += 1 below?
1. Locate the instance variable for class_v.
2. If there is no 1, find the class variable for class_v.
3. If no 2, create a class_v instance variable.

Comment: Yes, the retrieval of an attribute can inherit from the class, while assignment will assign directly into the object. A `+=` statement does *both* retrieval and assignment, which may be what lead to your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

> How does python work?

According to [Random Remarks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

> If the same attribute name occurs in both an instance and in a class,
> then attribute lookup prioritizes the instance

So python first look for instance variable, if it does not exist then class attribute is used.